# Configuring tnsnames.ora, listener.ora anf sqlnet.ora to connect visual studio 2010 to oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, tnsnames

I have been trying to access an Oracle Database from Visual Studio 2010.

I am confused about how to configure the tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora and listener.ora. I know they have to be moved into the Network/Admin folder of both the client and server but I don't know how and where to provide the instance name,user id and password of my specific database.

This is the information given in my Oracle Databse control window

Status  Up 
Up Since  Jun 1, 2011 8:37:15 AM CDT 
Instance Name  lorac 
Version  10.2.0.1.0 
Host  localhost.localdomain 
Listener  LISTENER_localhost.localdomain

The DBA admin has also given me the following information:

1. host: Lorac.chem.tamu.edu
2. instance: Stockroom2
3. user/password: Inventory_mgmt/invmgmt

I am very confused as to which data to include in tnsnames.ora,listener.ora and sqlnet.ora.

Please do help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to properly add a addres name to your TNSNAMES.ORA, for example:

```
MYCONNECTION.TEST =
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Lorac.chem.tamu.edu)(PORT = your server port))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME = your ORACLE server SID)
)
)
```

I don't know if your instance means the Schema name or the SID of the SERVER, if it's the SID you should put it in the text before as:

```
(SERVICE_NAME = Stockroom2)
```

like shown here [Configuring TNSNAMES.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora)

then in your app you use a connection string like this:

```
<add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=MYCONNECTION.TEST;User Id=Inventory_mgmt;Password=invmgmt;Integrated Security=no;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out the SID of the server. Also, do I not need to make any changes to listener.ora and sqlnet.ora?

Comment: I added the following in tnsnames.ora   
oradb1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lorac.chem.tamu.edu)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = lorac)
    )
  )  but I am getting

"ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect 
descriptor" when I try to add tes the data connection through the add connection function in the server explorer . Does this mean I have to onfigure listener.ora or does it mean by tnsnames.ora values are wrong?